# Why mysql_insert_id returns 0 in my case?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `pass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `lang` varchar(2) default NULL,
  `locale` varchar(2) default NULL,
  `pic` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `sex` char(1) default NULL,
  `birthday` date default NULL,
  `mail` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mail` (`mail`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

And this is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` (`name`, `mail`, `birthday`, `lang`, `locale`, `sex`, `pic`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".date_format($birthdaynew, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".substr($locale, 0, 2)."', '".substr($locale, -2, 2)."', '".$sex."', 'pic/".$uid.".jpg')";
$rows = mysql_query($query) or die("Failed: " . mysql_error());

$_SESSION['id']      = mysql_insert_id(); // I have tryed also mysql_insert_id($db_con) where $db_con is the link to db.
$_SESSION['name']    = $name;
```

$_SESSION['name'] contains correctly the name but $_SESSION['id'] contains 0. 
Why ? 
I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you are using INSERT IGNORE?

If you use INSERT IGNORE, then the row won't actually get inserted if there is a duplicate key (PRIMARY or UNIQUE), or inserting a NULL into a column with a NOT NULL constraint.

*Referring to the pass column, as you have not defined anything to insert into it, and it has NOT NULL constraint.*

EDIT:
*Referring also to the mail column, as you have a UNIQUE constraint on it.*

Comment: Yes, I am using INSERT IGNORE because if there is a duplicate do nothing.

Comment: You have NOT NULL constraint for your "pass" column, so you would need to insert something for the "pass" column. Can you try adding something to it and see if it is still failing?

Comment: Yes but there is " default '' ". Anyway if insert something in pass, I get always 0 :(

Comment: Then can you make sure that the data you are inserting into the "mail" column, has not been entered before? It has the unique constraint on it.

Comment: Yes, I erase the database before to try this query... So in the database there is nothing.

Comment: Hmm not sure as to why that isn't working, the only thing left I can recommend is to use mysql_info (http://php.net/mysql_info) immediately after you execute your query and see if you get any warnings or duplicate messages.

Comment: I have just removed IGNORE and now I get the last id. The problem is that I need to use IGNORE. Why it doesn't work with IGNORE ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12286/discussion-between-patyx7-and-xrobot)